# Forking Multiple Apps Under Python Subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I have been looking through Google and SO for something that could help me solve this but I have run into a block. I am a bit new to Python but I am looking for a way to run multiple apps that will continuously run in the background.

For example, I need 4 apps to start up with a param -appnum set to a different value. I would like to use python to count up and then start up a new app that will continue to run.

I assumed I would use subprocess but I feel a bit overwhelmed by the documentation.

I also plan to have the app print out sequences of numbers and would like to redirect this to a file. I noticed some of the SO questions talked about this, but I am a little confused on what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to start might be to use [`os.popen()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.popen), like this:

```
import os

subprogs = [None] * 4
for i in range(4):
    subprogs[i] = os.popen("app -appnum " + i, "r")
```

From here, you can read from each `subprog[i]` just like a file, capturing the output of the `app` program.

Note that although the documentation says this function has been deprecated, it still works perfectly fine for many purposes. You can explore the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module when you're more familiar with the limitations of `os.popen()`.

Comment: Note that `os.popen` is deprecated in favour of the `subprocess` module.

Comment: @Mike Graham: You're right, there are certainly more Pythonic ways of writing that code. I wanted to do something that was as simple as possible to read, since the OP indicated that he was new to Python. I'd probably have written that using a list comprehension instead of `append()` actually.

Comment: I don't really see how doing it this way makes things easier on a beginner. `list.__mul__` is a relatively obscure Python feature that seldom pops up in normal code, isn't clear from reading it what it does, and is a common source of beginner bugs. It is used in conjunction with iterating using indices, a pattern common in some languages, in which it's a frequent source of bugs. `list.append`, on the other hand, is self-documenting, constantly useful, and more idiomatic. I must just see this quite differently than you.